# Recursion and 'right hand side' in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I have seen the following function in Scala:

```
def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double =
    if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
    else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)
```

With the explanation:

> Note that sqrtIter is recursive, its right-hand side calls itself

Can someone explain what is meant by 'right-hand side' here?

Comment: FYI this is an example of tail recursion as sqrtIter is the last function to be called in the body of sqrtIter, which means this won't cause stackoverflow exception :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right hand side (rhs) and left hand side (lhs) are common words which describe the sides delimited by a delimiter sign.

For Scala the delimiter sign is the equal sign. This means that the lhs always specifies a definition, like

```
def sqrtIter(guess: Double, x: Double): Double
```

while the rhs always specifies the implementation, like

```
if (isGoodEnough(guess, x)) guess
else sqrtIter(improve(guess, x), x)
```

At the end lhs, rhs and the delimiter sign form the whole statement:

```
<lhs> = <rhs>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that to compute that return type, the Scala compiler would have to look at the right-hand side and because the square-root-Iter function is recursive it's stacked in a cycle.It would need the return type for that to compute the type for expression.To break the cycle, we require that recursive functions always have **explicit** return types.